# Do I Have A Huawei Developer Account?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

everyone

I got an email from Huawei informing that I am already registered in the Developer Alliance Forum. I would like to know if this means that I also have a Huawei Developer Account and if I can upload an app in the HUAWEI AppGallery ?

Answer (score 0):

If I remember right, you will also need to open up the [console](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/console). There you'll get forwarded to a login and afterwards need to provide some identification information in order to complete the registration.

The information you have to submit take one or two days to be confirmed and are only there to verify your identity, because at the moment all of the services are for free.

Answer (score 0):

Try logging into the Huawei AppGallery Console. You should be able to if you have finished the Developer registration process.
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/console

Otherwise you'll need to create a Developer Account using a Huawei ID and complete the identity verification process required to publish apps to AppGallery.
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/start/10104